# What method within view is notified when view is displayed on ui

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, surfaceview, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create a custom surfaceview where every time the view is on the screen the view will start playing a video on its own. I was wondering what method within View is notified when a view is displayed on the UI and seen by the user. I'm using a viewpager so the SurfaceCreated doesn't work because views are created before they are displayed on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried one of the three big view layout passes (check first to make sure you only start the video once)- `draw`, `layout` and `measure`? Since (and *only* since) you're using a view pager, you might have no choice but to use `draw`- don't forget to call super. Finally, if this is a view pager, have you considered setting an `AnimationListener` on the animation that brings your video view in, and starting the video `onAnimationEnd`- that's what I'd do.

Comment: I tried that but onDraw doesn't seem to get called. The surface is being created and destroyed though.

Comment: I just realized I'm using SurfaceView instead of just View I don't know if this changes things.

Comment: Why don't you set up your video when everything is created, get it ready, but don't play it. Then listen for the "flip in" animation end on the view flipper to call start?

Comment: If the `ViewPager` containing the custom View is shown from the start then use `onResume()` and start the video for the visible page(and after that use the `OnPageChangeListener`). If the `ViewPager` is added in the layout at a later point then start the video from the `onAttachedToWindow()` method of the `ViewPager`(for the visible page) and use `OnPageChangeListener` afterwards.

Comment: @Tom I'm trying to flip through a bunch of videos that people take themselves and it will constantly be in flux so all of them will have different filepaths. Luksprog I tried that but onResume is called before the views are created so that wouldn't work.

Comment: You add the views at a later time? The onResume callback is called just before the activity becomes completely visible to the user.

Comment: Yes, the views will be constructed, and indeed, inflated, in onCreate, most likely. I think by created, you mean ever drawn to a canvas. I still don't see what's wrong with listening to the view flipper animations and waiting for them to finish, and then setting up the video and running it- will take no time at all with a half decent SD card (even if your vids are on the SD). If your underlying data set is constantly changing, perhaps you just need to use the adapter pattern, but beyond that I see no problem.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your help! I took your advice but applied it a little differently. I used setPrimaryItem to initialize and start the Mediaplayer each time rather than using the pagefliiper animation end. However, initializing and starting each time works fine so your advice is spot on.

Comment: Oh really glad this helped! Perhaps I should add it as an answer, and then you can add yours too, and then accept yours as that's actually what worked in the end.

Answer (score 1):

**How to start a video automatically in a view pager when it comes on the screen**

This was the underlying problem. The OP, wisely, wanted to try and isolate the point where it, in a sense "comes on to the screen". Problem is that this can mean many things:

When I first heard the question, I thought a good case would be `onAttachedToWindow` - see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29). For people reading this question based on its original title, this is what you want.

The view is inflated and created in the Activity's onCreate *in most cases* (e.g. if you've used setContentView).

The OP had had no luck with surfaceCreated callbacks either. So we considered in the comments above whether the OP would be interested in the three draw stages `layout`, `measure` and `draw`. There are two stages to actually "putting a view on the screen" in android - the measuring, and the layout pass- see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

Problem would be that it turned out that the OP was **animating** his view onto the screen, so the question became how do you tell when a view "arrives" on the screen after animation.

**The important point is**: you actually wanted to detect a stage much much later in the drawing process, which is understandable! Animation works by many calls to `invalidate` which in turn require many `draw`s for that view's `Canvas` - so the stage at which you want to play the video is by no means when the view is first displayed in the UI.

**Solution for this particular scenario**.

Use animation listeners on your `ViewAnimator` instances (e.g. `ViewPager`). To not have to bother with them in teh activity, I would roll your own view, and then use the `Adapter` type patterns Android is so fond of to manage constantly changing data:

a very hastily written implementation would be:

```
public class VideoStartingViewFliper extends ViewFlipper {
private final Animation fromRight;
private final Animation toLeft;
private final Animation fromLeft;
private final Animation toRight;
private VideoViewAdapter mAdapter;

public VideoStartingViewFliper(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    fromRight = new YourChoiceOfAnimation();
    fromRight.setAnimationListener(videoStartingAnimationListener);

    toLeft = new YourChoiceOfAnimation();
    toLeft.setAnimationListener(videoStartingAnimationListener);

    fromLeft = new YourChoiceOfAnimation();
    fromLeft.setAnimationListener(videoStartingAnimationListener);

    toRight = new YourChoiceOfAnimation();
    toRight.setAnimationListener(videoStartingAnimationListener);
}

static interface VideoViewAdapter {

    public String getVideoPath(int childId);

}

public void setVideoViewAdapter(final VideoViewAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
}

// or even call this showNextVideo and don't override!
@Override
public void showNext() {
    setInAnimation(fromRight);
    setOutAnimation(toLeft);
    super.showNext();
}

@Override
public void showPrevious() {
    setInAnimation(fromLeft);
    setOutAnimation(toRight);
    super.showPrevious();

}

private final AnimationListener videoStartingAnimationListener = new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(final Animation animation) {
        final VideoView video = ((VideoView) getCurrentView());
        video.stopPlayback();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {
        final VideoView video = ((VideoView) getCurrentView());
        // check null here!
        video.setVideoPath(mAdapter.getVideoPath(getCurrentView().getId()));
        video.start();
    }
};
}
```

Hope this helps.